# image is not showing

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, awt

here is my little code. there is a button added to applet. button has a image icon. when i run this from server the code is running ok, but without the image on the button.

directory of the .java file:C:\Program Files\OpenLaszlo Server 4.9.0\Server\lps-4.9.0\App i am generating the class files here. i am keeping the html file here. also, image folder is in this folder. code of the html:

```
<html>
<applet code="applet.class" width="800" height="600">
</applet>
</html> 


/*
```

*here is the .java code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 *
 * @author USER
 */
public class applet extends Applet {
    JButton button;
    URL url;
    Image myImage;
    ImageIcon myIcon;


    public void init(){



       button = new JButton();
       this.add(button);


       try{
                 url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "image/REC1.jpg");
           }catch(Exception e){}
         myImage = getToolkit().createImage(url);
         myIcon = new ImageIcon(myImage);
//         myIcon = new ImageIcon("image/REC1.jpg");
         button.setIcon(myIcon);
    }

    public void paint(){



    }
}
```

Comment: may be the url is wrong. and some exception is occuring. However you are doing nothing inside catch block. Try printing exception object. See if any exception is there

Comment: Change `}catch(Exception e){}` to `System.out.println(url); }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` and copy/paste the output.  Still waiting on the HTML, & directory listing/structure for the HTML, class/jar and image.

Comment: output: file:C:/Users/USER/Desktop/app5 (1)/app5 (1)/serverclient/build/classes/image/REC1.jpg

Comment: @Andrew Thompson:
directory of the .java file:C:\Program Files\OpenLaszlo Server 4.9.0\Server\lps-4.9.0\App
i am generating the class files here. i am keeping the html file here. also, image folder is in this folder.
code of the html:
<html>
<applet code="App7.class" width="800" height="600">
</applet>
</html>

Comment: I was about to say 1) **give the copy/pasted directory listing** 2) And edit all the information **into the question** ..when I noticed `code="App7.class"`  ***What?!?***  With the code already in the question (`applet.java` -> `applet.class`), the applet should not even be loading at all!

Comment: sorry, my mistake. it is code="applet.class".

Comment: but the html is still not showing any images.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this, and it's working:

```
        URL url = applet.class.getResource("/image/"+name_of_picture);
        Image I = this.getToolkit().getImage(url);
```

Comment: I am using netbeans. I have created a image folder under the same directory as build and src. In the image folder, i have a image named REC1.jpg. i am using this image.

Comment: It seems that you need to create your image folder inside the src to be copied to the compiled bytecode where it can be accessed. http://capturevision.wordpress.com/2008/06/28/how-to-embed-resource-files-using-netbeans/

Comment: ok. it is working fine. but now, i have another problem. when i am running the html file, generated by the netbeans, from the server(apache tomcat), some errors sre occuring .. i dont know about the errors. the browser is not showing the type of errors.

Comment: Is it working in an emulator? Have you compiled it into a jar file or copied the image directory with the code?

Comment: sorry i am not understanding what you are saying. what i have done is that, i put the image folder under src directory and then compiled and run the code in netbeans.

Comment: Check if the image directory is copied to the directory where your class files are. If not, you placed it to the wrong place or haven't clean and build your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
 url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "/image/REC1.jpg");
```

Comment: no,but i am trying not to use absolute path, because i want it to run from a server embedded in a html file.